# Require other requirejs apps

Tags: requirejs

Is it possible to require another requirejs app (with its own config) as a requirejs package? Say I have my main app and I want to require my standalone calendar widget. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance

**edit**

One way could be to require the optimized version of the widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RequireJS and CurlJS (the more commonly-used AMD loaders) allow you to re-configure local scope. See [multiversion support docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#multiversion)

However, here is just a thought:

Rely as little as possible on config. It is very possible to set up only true generic, global things like `jquery`, `underscore` paths in global config and just roll named defines inside your widget for local packaging needs. For every config option James invented, there is a valid way to do it without a config.

Shim can be easily emulated locally with nested require calls. Putting all plain JS aliases inside `paths` is perhaps useless because you can just as easily use direct refs to the plain js files "path/to/file**.JS**"

In reality, you don't really need config that much. Get away from needing it and your problem is simplified.

Comment: So you mean that is better to require the full path to the file instead of using the config's mapping? Will r.js have any problem with that?

Comment: @chchrist Referencing plain JS as full resouce ID (absolute or relative to page URI) is part of the spec. It is hard to imagine James did not wire it up into `r.js`  The point of my comment was: your question was about using a widget that comes not only with modules but also with its own config. You can avoid "its own config" part by making all resources relative inside the widget. Then importing just the module becomes easy. [One warning though about loading plain JS files](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/requirejs/_kjtTyRvKe8/C2V276eYW5oJ). Suggest using "path/to/plain" (no `.js` ending).

Comment: The problem with that is that the resources are relative to the app that required the app. So if I have two folders app1,app2 and try to load app2 into app1 the urls are relative to app1...

Comment: Should I define it as a package in the config of app1?

Comment: You would define the parts that are internal to the package as relative refs, but would require the whole package's main file as full, resolved, not-relative. Example `./template.file.md` inside, but you ask for whole package by full address `libs/package.a`

Comment: Cool thnx, that makes sense. Another quick question... Do you know if it is possible to share config paths to loaded packages?

Comment: The `require.config()` call allows you to reconfigure the requirejs on the fly, but I believe it "adds" to global  config, and does not create a "scope" that just belongs to the package.